# SQL joining of two different queries

Tags: sql

`Table1`: column is( `ID`)
`Table2`: column is (`NAME`)

QUERY:

```
 SELECT ID FROM TABLE1

 SELECT NAME FROM TABLE2
```

NOW, I want output side by side , is there any possibility

Comment: `SELECT ID, NAME` ???

Answer (score 0):

Try this....
if this is without any condition

```
 select id, name from table1, table2
```

Answer (score 0):

I woder whether you mean `CROSS JOIN`

```
select id, name 
  from table1
  cross join table2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an JOIN between tables on a value that exists in both tables. An INNER JOIN only takes rows that has a match in both tables.

Example:

```
SELECT tb1.id, tb2.name FROM table1 AS tb1 INNER JOIN table2 AS tb2 ON tb1.id = tb2.table1_id;
```